# How can I turn this Recursive program to Dynamic one?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, non-recursive

I got below recursive function written in Java. I wanted to convert it to a Dynamic program but I don't know it is right or not? I think I'm missing something here. Any guidance would be perfect.

```
//Prints newRec(4,4) for example.
public static int newRec(int k, int t){
     if (k<3)
         return 1;
     if (t<3)
         return 2;
     return newRec(k-1,t-1)+newRec(k-1,t-2)+newRec(k-2,t-3);
 }
```

Dynamic program

```
public static int newDP(int k, int t) {
    //Initialize 2D Array to save bottom-up values
    int[][] saved = new int[k + 1][t + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i<=k; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<=t; j++)
                {   
                    //Eliminate constants. saved[0][j]=saved[1][j]=saved[2][j]=1
                    if(i < 3 ) {
                        saved[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                    //Eliminate constants. saved[i][0]=saved[i][1]=saved[i][2]=2
                    else if(j < 3 ) {
                        saved[i][j] = 2;
                    }
                    //Calculate rest of the values until you reach the wanted newDP(k, t)
                    else {
                        saved[i][j] = saved[i - 1][j - 1] + saved[i - 1][j - 2] + saved[i - 2][j - 3];
                    }
                }

            }
    //Return wanted value        
    return saved[k][t];
}
```

Best.

Comment: The scope of your memoizing array (`saved`) is too restricted. It needs to encompass the function definition, or to be given as an argument to the function.

Comment: Actually it did. I got right answers. However DP loop cycle count greater than Recursive one. It should lower than recursive, right?